# Writing spark dataframe to Cloud Storage throws error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage

I have a dataframe "df", which I want to store in Cloud Storage Bucket "my_bucket". I am currently writing my code on Google Colab. My code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2],
    'b': [2, 4]
}))

df.write.csv('gs://my_bucket/df')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o128.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "gs"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:851)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Anyone have any suggestions for this? Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you, that spark does not understand the path to your bucket. It looks like you have to mount the bucket first.

Try this:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Authenticate your user

Then install `gcsfuse` with the following snippet:

```
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
!apt -qq update
!apt -qq install gcsfuse
```

Then you can mount the bucket as following:

```
!mkdir mybucket
!gcsfuse mybucket mybucket
```

You can store your data then to the following path:

```
df.write.csv('/content/my_bucket/df')
```

Check out also [this medium post](https://medium.com/@gsalazarl021990/pyspark-google-colab-to-practice-d699688ac05e) for the detailed workflow.